# Unable to receive precise pen input in a QQuickWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I found no way to handle stylus input in QML so I subclass a `QQuickWindow` and set it as my root window in my QML app:

```
#ifndef TABLETWINDOW_H
#define TABLETWINDOW_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickWindow>

class TabletWindow : public QQuickWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TabletWindow();
    void tabletEvent(QTabletEvent* event) override{
        qDebug() << event->posF();
    }

#endif // TABLETWINDOW_H
```

The debug output shows that the positions of the tablet events have no double precision (e.g QPoint(200,300). Then I tested the same thing using `QMainWindow` and Qt widgets:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(){}
    void tabletEvent(QTabletEvent* event){
        qDebug() << event->posF();
    }

};
```

With the widgets approach the event do have double precision (and hence are much more precise). I am a bit confused by this since I thought `QQuickWindow` and `QMainWindow` both subclass `QWindow` and hence there shouldn't be much difference between their virtual function signatures. 
I have tested this on Windows 10 with Qt 5.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating this, I notice that using [`QTabletEvent::highResGlobalX`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabletevent.html#hiResGlobalX) and [`QTabletEvent::highResGlobalY`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabletevent.html#hiResGlobalY) I get the coordinates with double precision. This is very strange and annoying since I had to use `QWindow::mapFromGlobal`, which only operates on `QPoint`, so I had to get the integer parts of the coordinates (using `std::modf`) and then construct pass a QPoint and create a new QPointF with the addition of the fractional parts of the coordinates.